# Jupyter notebook kernel error exclusively when running it as a systemctl service

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have the following service file:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter-Notebook Daemon

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "~/mambaforge/envs/main/bin/jupyter-notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir=~/Code/notebooks"
User=<my_user>
PIDFile=/run/jupyter-notebook.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(notice I use **mambaforge** instead of miniconda). When I run the command under ExecStart as-is in my command line, the server starts and upon opening a notebook, kernel initializes correctly.

However, when it gets launched as a service (e.g. `sudo systemctl start jupyter-service`), kernel fails to connect. It gives a very long error message but the important part is this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/miniconda3/envs/main/bin/python'
```

Notice how it attempts to run from *miniconda3* (which doesn't exist)!
Why is this?

For reference when running `jupyter kernelspec list` I get a correct kernel path:

```
Available kernels:
  %s    %s python3        ~/mambaforge/envs/main/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

and using `cat ~/mambaforge/envs/main/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json` return:

```json
{
 "argv": [
  "~/mambaforge/envs/main/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

I'd like to know where is Jupyter looking for the python kernel in? And why?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using the powershell interactive kernel.   I had to add "Environment" in the service file that matched my user's path.

```
echo $PATH
```

in the .service file:

```
[Service]
Environment="PATH=yourResultsFromTheEcho"
```

In essence the Jupyter kernel for dotnet needed access to /home/user/.dotnet/tools where the executable of "dotnet-interactive" lives

ref: https://medium.com/@desjoerdhaan/manage-your-jupyter-server-with-systemd-9914ff39049d